# Not getting output from websocket-bench when testing Primus

Tags: node.js, benchmarking, primus

Hopefully this tool isn't too obscure and somebody can help me out, since it would be super useful if I could figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm running

```
websocket-bench -t primus -p engine.io https://dev.example.org.
```

I see a bunch of connections and eventually disconnects on the server so it's definitely hitting it, but the program hangs on my command line with this:

```
Launch bench with 100 total connection, 20 concurent connection
0 message(s) send by client
1 worker(s)
WS server : primus
```

Even when I kill the server, no output. I tried running with the -v option but no luck. I tried a trivial example with -a 1, same thing.

It's *kind of* useful like this since at least I can see that opening 10k concurrent connections isn't causing anything catastrophic on the server, but it would be really nice to see the neat table that I can get it to output when I use an incorrect transport like this:

```
websocket-bench -t primus -p websockets -v https://dev.example.org
```

Anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like a bug for websocket-bench, I was experiencing this as well. Try to submit a ticket at their github.